Sum/Average up all percentage value column for metrics
I have a pandas dataframe as below :

I want to get display the grand total in streamlit metrics UI. How do i get sum/average of all the percentage values
I tried below code:
#compute top analytics
    total_investment = df['Investment']
    
    total1,total2,total3,total4,total5=st.columns(5,gap='small')
    with total1:
        st.info('Sum Investment',icon="")
        st.metric(label="Sum TZS",value=f"{total_investment}")

below is the result i get


 import pandas as pd
 import streamlit as st
   data = {
        'SA': ['47.96%', '46.30%', '65.19%', '54.26%', '90.74%', '70.16%']
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['SA'] = df['SA'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
    sum = df['SA'].sum()
    avg = df['SA'].mean()
    st.metrics(
       label="sum",
       value=f"{sum:.2f}%",
)
    st.metrics(
       label="avg",
       value=f"{avg:.2f}%",
)

Use this code and try it once
